# How do I override an anchor focus rule with nothing?

Tags: css

I'm developing some changes to a page and the current CSS rule is a:focus { color: red }. We don't want that for a page. We just want the focus to do nothing at all. I don't want to override it with a:focus {color: black} to keep it as black (as this then interferes with hover). I just want it to be more like a:focus {color: unchanged}

Comment: If you're going to do this please bear in mind that any sighted user that, for any reason, uses keyboard navigation may not know which link is highlighted. Removing the focus indicator is bad user interface and reduces accessibility (though there are other visual markers besides `color` you could easily use to indicate focus).

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use color:initial instead. It isn't supported in IE, but that's not such a big thing anymore.
Also try all:revert or all:unset. I don't think this is completely cross-browser compatible so maybe try all 3 together.

Answer (score 0):

I would use **color:inherit** to return it to a normal value, which is what the color property does anyway in elements. It inherits them from parents. "inherit" erases the current assigned value on your element and says "just pass through me the text color every other element inherits and uses". So the text looks like any other text color you are using. Inherit is also supported across all browsers, including Internet Explorer.

Some browsers may assign special colors to anchor element "psuedo-classes" like "focus". But for focus its not so common as the others. If you think you might be needing to see that special color return then you can try "color:revert" (for non-IE browsers only) on an element using the "a:focus" psuedo-class. This should reset an anchor element BACK to its "psuedo-class" browser default focus color, if it exists. But I would not trust that.

To manage resets and defaults, I always assign my psuedo-class anchor elements a custom text link color in my "reset" style sheet so they start with a basic color shared across every browser and version. When I need to return my links back to those values, its very easy to then create selective styles to reset them.